# Update/Add/Delete EF with Navigation Property not working with ApplyCurrentValues

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I tried to update the existing user object into DB using Entity Framework.

I newly added some UserFavourite items and sent to UpdateUser method. But it saves only Id and Name, not UserFavourites.

**My Controller code**

```
List<UserFavourite> submittedFavouriteCollection=//prepared from view

User existingDBUser = AdminService.SelectUserById(int Id);

foreach (UserFavourite fav in submittedFavouriteCollection)
   { 
      fav.Modified = currentTime;
      fav.Modifier = modifier;
      existingDBUser.UserFavourites.Add(fav);

   }
AdminService.UpdateUser(existingDBUser);
```

**EF Class skeleton and Update method**

```
public class User{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public EntityCollection<UserFavourite> UserFavourites{get;set;}
    //other EF properties
}

public User UpdateUser(User userToSave)
{
    using (MyContext entities = new MyContext(GetSqlConnectionString()))
    {
        var usr = from rd in entities.Users
                    where rd.Id == userToSave.Id
                    select rd;


        userToSave.Modified = DateTime.Now;

        entities.Users.ApplyCurrentValues(userToSave);

        entities.SaveChanges();
        return userToSave;
    }
 }
```

***How can i add/delete/update favourites of the User in Entity Framework? What is the right way of doing?***

Answer (score 0):

The `EntityCollection<UserFavourite>` needs to be virtual.